# When I use NSPasteboard I met Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspasteboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [symbol(s) not found in XCode, Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159227/symbols-not-found-in-xcode-cocoa-application)

Below is the error information

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_NSPasteboardTypeString", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPasteboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

below is the code. Should I include more header?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/NSPasteboard.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        NSString *content = [pasteboard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
        NSLog(@"%@", content);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, am I missing something, or is this really not related to Xcode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [symbol(s) not found in XCode, Cocoa application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159227/symbols-not-found-in-xcode-cocoa-application) and [symbols not found for architecture i386](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839981/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386) and **loads** of similar questions.

Comment: Not that this would solve this problem, but you should not import specific classes' headers. You should import each framework's top-level header—the one with the same name as the framework—only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

correctly link against AppKit.framework, headers dont contain the 'real' code

Comment: Yep, that's it. (Is Google down again or what?)

Comment: Google is working fine for me